# Accessing Connection property using DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I am upgrading my practice Entity Framework code to v4.1. In old version, I had my context class deriving from ObjectContext but with new release of EF 4.1, they have provided a good DbContext API.

I am basically trying to convert the code so that it works from Database First approach to Code First approach. Playing around with EF 4.1

In old code, I had something like

```
context.Connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
```

where the context Type was deriving from ObjectContext.

In v4.1 I haven't got access to Connection property from context. How can I do that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is in the DbContext and it should be public.

```
dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

also:

```
dbContext.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel)
```

Answer (score 11):

In the brave new .Net Core world, you can use:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

context.Database.GetDbConnection();
```

Answer (score 4):

The new DBContext has

```
context.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction()
```

method with some overloads. Do a Goto Definition in Visual Studio to see the methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
```